# Use case for jQuery promise refactoring

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, refactoring

I'm wondering if it is possible to refactor this pseudo-code:

```
function foo() {
   if (condition) {
      return somethingReturningPromise().then(function (data) {
         doSomethingOnSuccess(data);
         return mainFunctionReturningPromise(); // here ...
      }, function () {
         return mainFunctionReturningPromise(); // here ...
      });
   }
   return mainFunctionReturningPromise(); // and here !!!
}

// ... somewhere ...
foo().done(function () {
   // here, mainFunctionReturningPromise successfully resolved
   continueProgram();
});
```

As you can see, `mainFunctionReturningPromise` is called in all possible cases:

1. if condition is met and `somethingReturningPromise()` is on success
2. if condition is met and `somethingReturningPromise()` is on failure
3. if condition is not met

Because of the special treatment provided by `doSomethingOnSuccess(data)`, I cannot seem to find a way to refactor the 3 calls to `mainFunctionReturningPromise`. Can you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for readability and understandability, I'd probably go with something like this:

```
function foo() {
    if (condition) {
        return somethingReturningPromise().then(doSomethingOnSuccess, function(err) {
            // log, but ignore error
            console.log(err);
            return $.when();     // return resolved promise to flip state to resolved in older versions of jQuery
        }).then(mainFunctionReturningPromise);
    } else {
        return mainFunctionReturningPromise();
    }
}
```

This calls `mainFunctionReturningPromise()` in two places, but I think it optimizes for easy to follow the logic.

---

If you only want to call `mainFunctionReturningPromise()` in one place, you could do this:

```
function foo() {
    var p = $.when();   // shortcut to get a resolved promise in jQuery
    if (condition) {
        p = p.then(somethingReturningPromise).then(doSomethingOnSuccess, function(err) {
            // log, but ignore error
            console.log(err);
            return $.when();     // return resolved promise to flip state to resolved in older versions of jQuery
        });
    }
    return p.then(mainFunctionReturningPromise);    
}
```

---

One of the horrors of jQuery promises is that with jQuery 1.x and 2.x, providing a handler for the 2nd parameter of `.then()` does not follow the Promise specification and does NOT change the promise to be resolved.  You  have to explicitly return a resolved promise or a promise that will eventually resolve to get the catch handler to do its proper job.  This has been fixed in jQuery 3.x.  That's why I `return $.when();` from the catch handler here to make sure that the promise flips to the resolved state and thus continues with other succeeding `.then()` handlers in all versions of jQuery.

FYI, there's nothing magic about using `$.when()` here.  It's just the shortest way I'm aware of to get a resolved promise in jQuery.  Way shorter than `$.Deferred().resolve().promise()` which would be the text book way of doing it in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

- Refactor to an empty `catch` handler that just ignores the error, and then chain one `mainFunctionReturningPromise` call to it
- Refactor the `else` branch to also return an empty, fulfilled promise, so that you can chain `mainFunctionReturningPromise` to it

```
function foo() {
    var p = condition
      ? somethingReturningPromise().then(function(data) {
            doSomethingOnSuccess(data);
            return undefined;
        }, function(err) {
            // ignore error
            return undefined;
        })
      : $.Deferred().resolve(undefined).promise();
    return p.then(mainFunctionReturningPromise);
}
```

<sub>(The `undefined`s can be omitted, I just included them to be explicit about the `mainFunctionReturningPromise` argument)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For `mainFunctionReturningPromise` to appear once, it needs to be a `.then()` callback at the end of a promise chain.

To guarantee `.then()` is available, you need a guaranteed promise, regardless of the outcome of outcome of `if (condition)`.

This can be achieved in a number of ways.

An interesting way is to "turn the code inside-out". Start with a resolved promise (`$.when()` in jQuery) and perform the decision making (`if (condition){...}`) downstream, in a chained `.then()`.

```
function foo() {
    return $.when() // resolved promise
    .then(function() {
        if (condition) {
            return somethingReturningPromise().then(doSomethingOnSuccess, function() {
                return $.when(); // this line may be omitted with jQuery 3+, where error handlers "catch" by default; but don't omit the function wrapper.
            });
        } // else `return undefined` is implicit.
    })
    .then(mainFunctionReturningPromise); // here's your single mention of `mainFunctionReturningPromise`, at the end of the chain.
}
```